Using array variable for converting to union type is not working as expected
The below code to convert array to union type should report error when trying to use an undefined key key4:
const keys = ['key1', 'key2'];

type KeyType = (typeof keys)[number];
type KeyValueType = { [K in KeyType]: string };

const tmp: KeyValueType = {
  key1: 'some string',
  key4: 'another string' // This should fail and shouldn't allow me to create an object
};

but this works:
const keys = ['key1', 'key2'] as const;

type KeyType = (typeof keys)[number];
type KeyValueType = { [K in KeyType]: string };

const tmp: KeyValueType = {
  key1: 'some string',
  key4: 'another string' // This fails as expected
};

Why is the first code block not working? What am I doing wrong?

The difference lies in how type TypeScript infers typeof keys. Per default TypeScript infers ['key1', 'key2'] as an arbitrary string array (=string[]). However, if you use a const-assertion, TypeScript will infer the most specific type possible. In your case that is the tuple type readonly ['key1', 'key2'].
TypeScript Playground
Therefore, the mapped type KeyValueType in your first example maps over K in string (=string) and essentially allows you to use any string key whereas your second example uses K in ['key1', 'key2'] (='key1' | 'key2') and limits you to a set of certain string keys.

Thanks @behemoth for the explanation. But how do I fix the first case where I should get specific type instead of string type. I am getting the array from other parts of code which is dynamic.

If you get the array dynamically as strings the only option left is to assert the array to your desired type: const keys = getKeys() as ['key1', 'key2']; (dangerous and not recommended)

But in this case, I need to know the keys beforehand, which I don't. If I know the keys, then I can use the second case from above.

Well then it's impossible. How do you expect the compiler to know the keys at compile time if you don't know them either?

Do we really need to know the keys, can't we just convert the array values to union type, just like it's been done in the second case?

How do you convert to something you don't know?
